# How to replace certain percentage of values with other values in image?

Tags: python, numpy

I have an RGB image, I have to assign certain percentage of brightest pixels to 255 and certain percentage of darkest pixels to 0 for each channel. Is there a simple way to do this in numpy?

Comment: Can you post your code?  This should be pretty easy.  Something like:  A = 255  if A > threshold else A.  It should be possible to apply the one expression to the whole matrix in one go.  You'll need to make sure the data is stored correctly though, i.e. integer rather than some kind of normalised float range.

Comment: @JohnForbes I said percentage of darkest pixel, suppouse if I have 101 as brightest pixel and there a 100 such pixels in whole image, i need to replace 5% of them with 255

Comment: Please share your latest/greatest attempt at coding this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to do it by sorting and finding the threshold and replacing them, however if you are looking for an efficient way, you really do not need to sort your image, you can use `np.partition` for it (your image is `arr` and I assume last dimension are for channels. Update 0.05 for desired percentage. For dark points it would be similar solution with minor changes):

```
b = arr.reshape(-1,arr.shape[-1])
n = int(0.05 * b.shape[0])
threshold = np.sort(b,0)[n]
arr[arr>threshold] = 100
```